# Do the search algorithms consider moves that decrease the hard score

Tags: optaplanner

For my optimization problem, I let OptaPlanner construct the initial solution (FIRST_FIT) and then do local search.

```
<unionMoveSelector>
    <changeMoveSelector/>
    <swapMoveSelector/>
    <pillarChangeMoveSelector>
        <subPillarType>ALL</subPillarType>
    </pillarChangeMoveSelector>
    <pillarSwapMoveSelector>
        <subPillarType>ALL</subPillarType>
    </pillarSwapMoveSelector>
</unionMoveSelector>
<acceptor>
    <entityTabuSize>7</entityTabuSize>
    <lateAcceptanceSize>400</lateAcceptanceSize>
</acceptor>
<forager>
    <acceptedCountLimit>1000</acceptedCountLimit>
</forager>
```

My problem has a 3-level score (hard/medium/soft), where 'hard' models the hard constraints and must become 0 in a feasible solution, 'medium' is my main optimization goal, and 'soft' is a sub-goal / tie breaker.

Now I inspect a solution and see that I can improve it in just 2 change moves, i.e. assign two planning entities a different value. But the first move makes the problem infeasible (i.e. decreases the hard score < 0). The second step increases the hard score back to 0, and has a higher medium score. However, whatever I try (longer calculation time, acceptedCountLimit=100000, etc) OptaPlanner does not find this solution.

Now I'm wondering if, during local search, OptaPlanner decides to hill-climb on the hard score, even if I configured local search as above. I expect not, but does anyone have a thought about where to look to improve this?

Comment: So this was not related to hard/medium scores. Step 1 did not decrease the hard score. But there was something special about the steps, related to the current planning value of the two involved planning entities, and the new planing value to which they were both assigned. So I created a custom Move tailored to this situation, with MoveIteratorFactory, following the CheapTime example. That solved my issue.

Comment: Now, my custom move is just two consecutive ChangeMoves, but that sequence was never found during many runs of the algorithm, even when I switched to NON_REPRODUCIBLE. This particular instance had just 100 planning entities and 400 planning values. That is 40k possible combinations, and hence a (1/40k)^2 probability that precisely the improving combination was found? I guess, course grained moves should become a standard part of my neighborhoods going forward?

Comment: Can you post the code for your CustomMove? Are you using CompositeMove?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: Yes, the algorithms in Optaplanner do consider moves that worsen scores. Under what condition they do depends on the algorithm, the configuration and its implementation.

I haven't looked into the specific implementations in Optaplanner but generally, in tabu search for example, a move is accepted if it improves a solution and the move is not on the tabu list, i.e. the move has been applied before sometime recently. When looking for a new move that will improve the current best solution, the algorithm will apply infeasible moves as well, usually in the hope to stumble upon a solution that improves the current best solution. However, *how* this exploration is done really depends on the implementation, [this section](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.40.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#localSearchConceptsDecideTheNextStep)  explains how Optaplanner steps through the options. Hope this has helped!